# Matching pattern over multiple lines in Python

Tags: python, regex

I am new to Python regex. I trying to get below lst from the output.

```
output="""
IP = 10.10.10.1
BGP version 4, remote router ID 0.0.0.0
State = Established
IP = 10.10.10.2
BGP version 4, remote router ID 0.0.0.0
State = Active
IP = 10.10.10.3
BGP version 4, remote router ID 0.0.0.0
State = Active
IP = 10.10.10.4
BGP version 4, remote router ID 0.0.0.0
State = Established
"""
```

I am trying with below regex but no luck. Can someone please help me.

```
lst = re.findall(r'IP = (\S+)\n\nState = (\S+)',output, re.M)
```

`lst` should be filled with

```
[('10.10.10.1', 'Established'), ('10.10.10.2', 'Active'), ('10.10.10.3', 'Active'), ('10.10.10.4', 'Established')]
```

Comment: Use [`re.findall(r'(?sm)^IP = (\S+).*?^State = (\S+)',output)`](http://ideone.com/q54dh3) if your input is well formatted and there is a `State` for each `IP`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew What is for (?sm). Could you please let me know ?

Comment: `re.DOTALL` + `re.MULTILINE`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks a lot...new learning for me :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
In [101]: pat = r'IP\s*\=\s*([^\n\r]*)[\r\n][^\=]*?State\s*\=\s*([^\n\r]*)'

In [102]: re.findall(pat, output, flags=re.M & re.S)
Out[102]:
[('10.10.10.1', 'Established'),
 ('10.10.10.2', 'Active'),
 ('10.10.10.3', 'Active'),
 ('10.10.10.4', 'Established')]
```

NOTE: please pay attention at [@WiktorStribiżew's RegEx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45774440/matching-pattern-over-multiple-lines-in-python/45774474#comment78507047_45774440), which is much more elegant:

```
re.findall(r'(?sm)^IP = (\S+).*?^State = (\S+)',output)
```

Comment: Why `[\r\n]`? As far as I know, all Unix systems use just `\n`, while Microsoft uses a sequence `\r\n`, but nobody uses `\r` alone.

Comment: @Błotosmętek, yes, but in `[]` RegEx we specify a list of symbols in __any__ order... ;-)

Comment: @Błotosmętek `\r` is a MacOS line break style.

Comment: Yes, I know how `[]` works - `[\r\n]` matches **either**  `\n` (Unix) or `\r` (???); it does not match `\r\n` (Microsoft) though… care to explain?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew funny, I thought MacOS X uses `\n` like all other Unix variants…

Comment: @Błotosmętek, yeah, i'm using `[\r\n]` in order to cover all popular OS's including MacOS (pre-OS X), wher `\r` is used as a line-break.